# How to set current_user id on a polymorphic model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How do I set the owner of a Rails record in this complex case.

I have User, Event, Tag models. Tag is polymorphic.

On the Event form I have a `:tag_ids` multiselect.

In the tag create controller I have:

```
def create
  klass = [Event, ...some other models.].detect { |t| params["#{t.name.underscore}_id"]}
  @taggable = klass.find(params["#{klass.name.underscore}_id"])
  @tag = @taggable.tags.new(params[:tag]
  if save.......
end
```

So far so good. But the Tag model also has a `:tagged_by_id` column, which I need to set to the current user.

```
@tag = @taggable.tags.new(params[:tag].merge(tagged_by_id: current_user.id))
```

seems like it should work. But it doesn't.

```
tagged_by_id = nil
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: please elaborate "doesn't work"

Comment: thanks shime. nothing is being set to the attribute. `tagged_by_id = nil`.

Comment: no problem :) i don't know how your code works, but i would check if it's getting saved to a db. is `current_user.id` even present? it's not throwing any exceptions? you should check if it gets stored to a db via `rails console`.

Comment: thanks shime. I'm working entirely in the console. Can you see any reason why my merge code above wouldn't work? It should be the equivalent of update_attributes correct, only occurring before the save?